# Reviewed not an answer, answer gets deleted, I got suspended

Tags: discussion, support, review-suspension

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11133421

Ok. This is strange behaviour. I flagged a late answer that was not an answer as not an answer. Answer gets deleted, I get a suspension for 7 days.

This is the question:

[How can I create an array of directory contents in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087850/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-directory-contents-in-perl/35181986#35181986)

Last flag on that question was my flag of deleted answer

There's no reason that I got banned. I reviewed properly. Why is this so?

Comment: [Your flag summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/5324723) is private - other (normal) users cannot see it. See, for comparison, [my flag summary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1364007).

Comment: All these upvotes made me think at first that people like the idea of you being unjustly banned. Had to remind myself that voting works in mysterious ways on meta... :)

Comment: Yeah, same thing with me. Firstly I thought that nobody cares and that it's a bug.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Ick, that was my mistake. My sincere apologies!

I've unbanned you now. Note to self: doublecheck the flags, you were *not* the one that approved that post.

Comment: Care adding a screenshot of the answer to your answer? helps us preventing future mistakes for the same kind of situation, or was the answer clear enough?

Comment: @Ferrybig: it was clear enough. It was a joke post about being a bot passing the turing test, clearly not an answer.

Comment: "you were not the one that approved that post." Wait, you mean somebody actually approved that crap???

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Could have been the respondent's mother.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Or father.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Or its bot.

Comment: @Dzyann one that passed the Turing Test OMG!

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro damn synths.

Comment: I've been banned for 7 days lately, and I'm sure it was a mistake. I just didn't know I can object here to cancel the suspension!

Comment: @AlexJolig: you were banned *automatically* for failing too many reviews.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. But the last one which got me banned was clearly a mistake

Comment: @AlexJolig: not so certain about that. See the username on that post? They don't appear to be here to answer, more to link to their site.